# Writing to/Reading from a Vector (or ArrayList) with two threads

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have two threads both of which accesses an Vector. t1 adds a random number, while t2 removes and prints the first number. Below is the code and the output. t2 seems to execute only once (before t1 starts) and terminates forever. Am I missing something here? (PS: Tested with ArrayList as well)

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Vector;

public class Main {

public static Vector<Integer> list1 = new Vector<Integer>();

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("Main started!");

    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("writer started! "); 
            Random rand = new Random();

            for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
                int x = rand.nextInt(100);
                list1.add(x);
                System.out.println("writer: " + x);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }               
        }

    });

    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("reader started! ");         
            while(!list1.isEmpty()) {

                int x = list1.remove(0);
                System.out.println("reader: "+x);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }               
        }

    });


    t2.start();
    t1.start();

    t1.join();
    t2.join();      
}
```

}
    Output:
    Main started!
    reader started! 
    writer started! 
    writer: 40
    writer: 9
    writer: 23
    writer: 5
    writer: 41
    writer: 29
    writer: 72
    writer: 73
    writer: 95
    writer: 46

Comment: Yes, when `t2` starts, there is nothing in the list, so the `while` terminates before it even begins.

Comment: Also a broken example since `ArrayList` isn't thread-safe and you don't have any external synchronization.

Comment: @RealSkeptic: is there a way to keep t2 working?

Comment: @Kayaman: I tested it with java.util.Vector as well. The result is the same. I think the main problem here is not syncronization but the fact that t2 is terminating as RealSceptic mentioned.

Comment: Well, how would you suggest it should know when to continue and when to terminate? What is the difference between the two situations? What should it be doing when the list is empty but it's not supposed to terminate yet?

Comment: I know what the main problem is. I was just mentioning that your example is broken.

Comment: @RealSceptic: I am trying to make t2 wait for t1 to add something to the list as long as the list is not empty. Then remove the first number. Do you think a lock would be necessary?

Comment: @Kayaman: Thanks for pointing that out. I will update the code to the Vector version.

Comment: May be it is better to implemet that functionality on Queue?

Comment: See, you don't have a clear definition of what you want. "make t2 wait for t1 to add something" = "When the list is empty, wait". "As long as the list is not empty" = "When the list is empty, leave". This is a contradiction in terms. You have to have a condition for termination that does not contradict your condition for continuing.

Comment: Don't use `Vector`, it's outdated. Use `Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());` instead. Your main problem is that your reader thread gets to exit too fast. I'm not entirely clear what you're even trying to do with this example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like a toy to understand concurrency, so I didn't mention it before, but I will now (at the top because it is important).

If this is meant to be production code, don't roll your own.  There are plenty of well implemented (debugged) concurrent data structures in java.util.concurrent.  Use them.

---

When consuming, you need to not shutdown your consumer based on "all items consumed".  This is due to a race condition where the consumer might "race ahead" of the producer and detect an empty list only because the producer hasn't yet written the items for consumption.

There are a number of ways to accomplish a shutdown of the consumer, but none of them can be done by looking at the data to be consumed in isolation.

My recommendation is that the producer "signals" the consumer when the producer is done producing.  Then the consumer will stop when it has both the "signal" no more data is being produced AND the list is empty.

Alternative techniques include creating a "shutdown" item.  The "producer" adds the shutdown item, and the consumer only shuts down when the "shutdown" item is seen.  If you have a group of consumers, keep in mind that you shouldn't remove the shutdown item (or only one consumer would shutdown).

Also, the consumer could "monitor" the producer, such that if the producer is "alive / existent" and the list is empty, the consumer assumes that more data will become available.  Shutdown occurs when the producer is dead / non-existent AND no data is available.

Which technique you use will depend on the approach you prefer and the problem you're trying to solve.

---

I know that people like the elegant solutions, but if your single producer is aware of the single consumer, the first option looks like.

```
public class Producer {

   public void shutdown() {
      addRemainingItems();
      consumer.shutdown();
   }
}
```

where the Consumer looks like {

```
public class Consumer {

   private boolean shuttingDown = false;

   public void shutdown() {
     shuttingDown = true;
   }

   public void run() {
     if (!list.isEmpty() && !shuttingDown) {
        // pull item and process
     }
   }
}
```

Note that such lack of locking around items on the list is inherently dangerous, but you stated only a single consumer, so there's no contention for reading from the list.

Now if you have multiple consumers, you need to provide protections to assure that a single item isn't pulled by two threads at the same time (and need to communicate in such a manner that all threads shutdown).

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation. I will start testing with semaphores and if that des not work try monitors.

Comment: Semaphores are one way of doing it, but there are simpler ways.

Comment: Edwin, You are very right! This is not a production code. Thanks for your awesome input.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a typical [Producer–consumer problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem). Try to have a look into [Semaphore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html).

Comment: It's more than a producer-consumer issue (overrun/underrun): the issue is how to decide between waiting to consume and terminating.

Comment: I will try semaphores.

Answer (score 0):

Update: The issue`s gone after changing the while loop in the consumer (reader). Instead of exiting the thread if the list is empty, it now enters the loop but does not do anything. Below is the updated reader thread. Of course a decent shutdown mechanism can also be added to the code such as Edwin suggested.

```
        public void run() {
        System.out.println("reader started! ");         
        while(true) {
            if(!list1.isEmpty()) {
                int x = list1.remove(0);
                System.out.println("reader: "+x);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }               
    }
```

Please note, this is not a code snippet taken from a real product or will go in one!